# If any rows contain the same data in some columns, move other columns in that row into new columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Sample data:

```
df<-data.frame(Country = c("FR", "FR", "US", "US", "US", "US", "AU", "UK", "UK", "UK"), 
Name = c("Jean","Jean","Rose","Rose","Rose","Rose","Liam","Mark","Mark","Mark"),
A=c(2,NA,NA,1,3,NA,1,2,NA,NA),
B=c(2,5,NA,1,NA,2,1,NA,3,NA),
C=c(2,NA,4,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
D=c(NA,3,NA,NA,4,4,1,2,4,4))
```

```
Input:   
  Country Name   A  B  C  D  
1      FR Jean   2  2  2  NA 
2      FR Jean   NA 5  NA 3  
3      US Rose   NA NA 4  NA 
4      US Rose   1  1  1  NA 
6      US Rose   3  NA NA 4  
7      US Rose   NA 2  NA 4  
8      AU Liam   1  1  NA 1  
9      UK Mark   2  NA NA 2  
10     UK Mark   NA 3  NA 4  
11     UK Mark   NA NA NA 4  

Desired output:
  Country Name   A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D 
1      FR Jean   2  2  2  NA NA 5  NA 3
2      US Rose   NA NA 4  NA 1  1  1  NA 3  NA NA 4  NA 2  NA 4    
3      AU Liam   1  1  NA 1  
4      UK Mark   2  NA NA 2  NA 3  NA 4  NA NA NA 4
```

As you can see from the data, the goal is:

- if Country and Name contains identical data for each subsequent row, move the data in columns ABCD in those rows into new ABCD columns.
- the actual table that I have do not contain just 11 rows. In subsequent rows (after row 11), the Country and Name data may be repeated 1, 2, 3,...n times. How do I make a CONDITIONAL such that, as long as the row below is identical, automatically move the data in ABCD to create new ABCD columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to have two columns with the same name. I don't know if it will help you, but you could do this:

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = A:D) %>%
  group_by(Country,name) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0(name,row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value)
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 18
# Groups:   Country [4]
  Country Name     A1    B1    C1    D1    A2    B2    C2    D2    A3    B3    C3    D3    A4    B4
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FR      Jean      2     2     2    NA    NA     5    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 US      Rose     NA    NA     4    NA     1     1     1    NA     3    NA    NA     4    NA     2
3 AU      Liam      1     1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 UK      Mark      2    NA    NA     2    NA     3    NA     4    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA
# ... with 2 more variables: C4 <dbl>, D4 <dbl>
```

Comment: Is there a way to force R to remove the numbers at the end of the colnames? In A1, B1, C1... etc.

Comment: As I said for data.frames you won't be able to have two columns with the same name

Answer (score 1):

It *is possible* to have *columns with the same name*, but it will not be recommended.

```
. <- split(df[-1:-2], df[1:2], TRUE)
. <- lapply(., \(x) c(t(x)))
. <- do.call(rbind, lapply(., `length<-`, max(lengths(.))))
colnames(.) <- rep(names(df)[-1:-2], length.out=ncol(.))
cbind(df[match(row.names(.), interaction(df[1:2], drop=TRUE)), 1:2], .)
#  Country Name  A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D
#1      FR Jean  2  2  2 NA NA  5 NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#7      AU Liam  1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#8      UK Mark  2 NA NA  2 NA  3 NA  4 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA
#3      US Rose NA NA  4 NA  1  1  1 NA  3 NA NA  4 NA  2 NA  4
```